# Issue in converting 3d numpy array to image in PIL

Tags: numpy, image-processing, python-imaging-library

Consider the following statement

```
PIL_att = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(one_map))
```

it is causing the error **TypeError: Cannot handle this data type: (1, 1, 48), |u1**

The shape of *one_map* is i.e., `print(one_map.shape)` gives **(272, 272, 48)**, the dimension is  i.e.,  `print("one_map.ndim)` gives **3** and `print(one_map.dtype)` is giving **float64**. Each data value in `np.uint8(one_map)` is an whole number that varies from 0 to 255.

What is the issue and how to resolve it?

Comment: Your image has `48` channels?

Comment: @QuangHoang Sorry, I am not sure about the terminology.

Comment: If I need to check with any extra code on one_map, I can do that.

Comment: @QuangHoang yeah, those are channels. Learned after reading this https://machinelearningmastery.com/a-gentle-introduction-to-channels-first-and-channels-last-image-formats-for-deep-learning/

Comment: None of the arrays in the link has `48` channels :-).

Comment: Yeah, but it is saying about channel-last  So i told @QuangHoang.

Comment: Please click `edit` under your question and add the output from `print(one_map.dtype)` and `print(one_map.shape)`. Thank you.

Comment: Does it represent 48 images, each one 272x272 pixels? If so, use `Image.fromarray(np_one[...,0])` for the first image.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Trying it.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Now, the line, now,  is not generating any error. But another error came. I think, the reason may be the above solution you told.

Comment: 'row = np.concatenate(row, 1)' .............
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in concatenate ..............
ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 2, the array at index 0 has size 3 and the array at index 2 has size 48

Comment: Please don't post code and error messages in comments - click `edit` under your question and edit it to make sure it is up-to-date and complete and all in one place so people can find the details without looking through all the comments. Thank you.